# TypeScript: restrict object keys by removing specific strings

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to define a record type which allows keys to be of all strings, except some few specific values. How can this be done? I have the following types:

```
// Actual type of KvValue is irrelevant here, but here is a subset of it
type KvValue = string | number | boolean

type Mutation<T extends KvValue> = (value: T) => KvValue

type MutationRecord<T extends KvValue> = Record<
  Exclude<string, "id" | "versionstamp" | "value">,
  Mutation<T>
>

const record: MutationRecord<number> = {
  id: (n) => n * 2,
}
```

A MutationRecord should never allow keys of "id", "versionstamp" and "value". I also need this to be inferred in union types so that some type T & MutationRecord knows that values from T with keys that are not allowed in MutationRecord do not receive the type Mutation, but only the type they have in T.

Comment: Depending on your use case, intersecting the record with another record of `never`s will work: https://tsplay.dev/WYlnzm

Comment: @kelsny This gives me a new issue where it says that the record is missing the properties id, versionstamp and value, which should have the type never.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an intersection with optional `never` for your forbiden keys:

```
type KvValue = string | number | boolean;

type Mutation<T extends KvValue> = (value: T) => KvValue;

type MutRecord<T extends KvValue> = Record<string, Mutation<T>> &
  {id?: never, versionstamp?: never, value?: never}

const record: MutRecord<number> = {
  id: (n) => n * 2, // error
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0gbgNQIYBsCu0C8UDOwBOAlgHYDmUAPlMWgLYBGE%20lU9A9myhEsQNwBQ-UJCgBZNMCTBCbYgB4AKlAgAPYBGIATHLESoMAPijYAFHH0QAXFAUBKY0fjJ0EAUPDRxwAEoQAxmz4morKahraus6GxlC%20AUFyeERkADRiElIy8goGRgBk-FBQAN6EmgD81sQQcExptfg4WXhItGCV1DV1UOYuHdUNAL6CAcR4UPj%20gZrWXnHTcjQMTEbYxYVQZdYmxPaYRsRQAFRQAEwp-IMCQA)

Comment: Its a bit weird that it now gives autocomplete for the exact keys I never want to allow, but this solution does in fact accomplish what I want, so thanks!

Comment: I think this still might interfere with union types though? T & MutationRecord, there will still be overlap if T has keys of id, versionstamp and value?

Comment: The `never` will make sure that I will never be valid.